# Response in ASP.net is not showing my custom header

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 and learning about adding custom headers to a Request.

```
void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(my_url_here);

    webRequest.Headers.Add("Hello", "World");

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

    Response.Write(r.ReadToEnd());

    Response.End();
}
```

I can use `xhr.setRequestHeader` through JavaScript and pick up my custom name/value in the response that way.

But, if I put a break point above after `.GetResponse` and inspect `resp.Headers.AllKeys` my custom header is not there. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure I understand you'r question but it seems to me you have a mix up.
if you set on client side an header you should search for it on the Request on Server side.
the Response (on server) is the Response you will send back to client